# php container class: why does everyone use the more complicated method?

Tags: php, containers

When I find scripts for php or look at php frameworks I see a "registry class" or a "container class" which often holds variables or other objects utilizing the __get magic method.

Here is a oversimplified example of what I mean:

**example 1:**

```
class container {
 private $objects;
 public function __get($class){
  if(isset($this->objects[$class])){
   return $this->objects[$class];
  }
  return $this->objects[$class] = new $class();
 }
}
```

the above example will have more functions to it when creating the class instead of just calling it but for my example it should be enough.
"example 1" is how I mostly see it in scripts downloaded from the internet, it maintains a single class instance, now what I'm wondering is that wouldn't this example do the same thing and be more efficient:

**example 2:**

```
class simplecontainer {
 public function __get($class){
  return $this->$class = new $class();
 }
}
```

But I never see "example 2" in other peoples scripts which makes me think twice before even considering to use it.

I tested container vs simplecontainer using several classes that they would contain and re-use around 100000 times and "example 1" does it in 0.75seconds on my local machine, and "example 2" does it in 0.29seconds.

which should I use in my scripts? example 1 or example 2? and why?

Comment: Looks like simplecontainer holds one object only at a time.

Comment: I tested it with 3 different objects, and it holds all 3, or did I misunderstand what you meant?

Comment: Maybe i'm overlooking sg but how do you refer these different objects?

Comment: $container = new simplecontainer(); $container->testclass->test();

Comment: @Yuri: what you wrote it doesn't makes any sense. This is what i call complicated and also useless.

Comment: you simply don't understand it yet fabrik, thanks for trying ;)

Comment: @Yuri if it so what do you think why the upvote in my first comment?

Comment: maybe you logged in with a different account... seriously man i dont want to start a fight here just because i fail to understand what you say.

Comment: It's a little bit hard what you sayin'.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Because in yours I can't do this:

```
class container {
    private $foo = "I'm only a var";
    private $objects;
    public function __get($class){
        if(isset($this->objects[$class])){
            return $this->objects[$class];
        }
        return $this->objects[$class] = new $class();
    }
}

class simplecontainer {
    private $foo = "I'm only a var";
    public function __get($class){
        return $this->$class = new $class();
    }
}

class foo {
    public $bar = "wibble";
}

$c1 = new container();
$c2 = new simplecontainer();

$foo = $c1->foo;
$foo->bar = "Don't you forget about me!";
unset($foo);
$foo = $c1->foo;
echo $foo->bar;
// Don't you forget about me!

$foo = $c2->foo;
$foo->bar = "Don't you forget about me!";
unset($foo);   
$foo = $c2->foo;
echo $foo->bar;
// wibble
```

Your version relies on no class name being the same as a private member of the container object. Ok, so it should be simple to avoid, but would be a pain tracking down a bug for. Safe coding means less stress.

Comment: im still thinking this through, but hmmm, I like less stress :D

Comment: It actually throws up some weird behaviour from PHP (no surprise). The simplecontainer in my example returns one `foo` object to the caller and then sets an entirely different one as the private method in the container. Seeing as how objects are meant to get passed by reference it's a bit wacky.

Comment: the unset() in your example seems like it does nothing? well, nothing to change the outcome at least.

Comment: yes, this is of great insight into the quirkyness of php xD, took me a while to understand the differences but is invaluable for me at least. Thank you for helping me fix my confusion!!

Comment: Had something in my head about clearing references when I wrote it. As you say, they're totally unnecessary.

Comment: I do agree with fabrik though, this isn't a registry.

Comment: I never said it was :) I only said that I often see objects stored in classes with registries or containers in a way that seemed inefficient to me.

Comment: You should use `array_key_exists()` instead of `isset()`, 1. to avoid notices about not existing array index, 2. to return null values

Answer (score 4):

Without first off example2 doesnt define the objects as `protected` or `private` which means that `simplecontainer::objects` will be a public member that can be overwritten like:

`$container->className = new SomethingElse();`

Comment: Wait, I thought that after creating the instance and storing it in a variable by doing this $this->$class = new $class(); it gets stored and it will no longer call __get on any subsequent calls? I will test this right away.

Comment: yes, im correct, it only gets called when creating the object and it stores it for the future ones, so your second point is wrong.

Comment: Yeah youre right... i overlooked the fact that it wasnt storing them in an `objects` member... ill edit. good catch.

Comment: @Yuri: you don't understand yet.

Comment: so the reason they use example 1 is just for a safeguard against people rewriting the object?

Comment: @YuriKolovsky: Yes. That's the point of a Registry. See the http://www.phppatterns.com/docs/design/the_registry link fabrik linked to.

Comment: And here we go again. An accepted answer while OP didn't learn anything. Then later today or tomorrow he will posting the same question over and over again. :(

Comment: You've constantly rave about registry classes but it's not my business. You'll use them how you want.

Comment: @prodigitalson the ability to overwrite a contained object just like that might be desirable if I would need a ability to "reset" the object variable, but obviously this could get very confusing very fast.

Comment: @yuri: but then you have no assurance that the new object/var will be an instance of `$class`.. something that could be mistakenly depended on by an assumed convention that doesnt exist :-) kind of goes to Mike's point in the marked answer.